# What tense is the 'come' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, sentence-patterns, ellipses

Is 'come' in the following sentence the base form or the past participle?

> “And Royce seemed to be everything I’d dreamed of. The fairy tale
> prince, come to make me a princess. Everything I wanted...”

If it's a past participle then is it a similar usage of `come` as in `This is my dream come true`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postmodification using participle: Is it grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327320/postmodification-using-participle-is-it-grammatical) (A: What is your favorite movie? ... B: It is Titanic[,] created in 1997 by James Cameron.) Compare ' ... which was created ...' / ' who has [is!] come ...'.

Comment: Sorry, not really. But I get when past participles act like post-positive adjectives. So are you saying it's the same case with 'The fairy tale prince, come to make me a princess. ' ? And even though it's punctuated with a period it's actually a noun phrase?

Comment: There is no sentence: it's a fragment. Compare 'It was Sue, sitting in the shade.' Or if you need the to-infinitive, 'It was John, trying to knit a jumper.' Or closer still, a fragment: 'Who should I find in the kitchen? My brother, trying to make me a souffle.' 'Who was / who had' 'make these into' (non-defining) relative clauses.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret it as the past perfect used in an elided phrase.

Also, the second "sentence" in the passage is actually just a sentence fragment—which can be quite all right, stylistically speaking.

To paraphrase and slightly restructure the passage, consider this:

> “And Royce seemed to be everything I’d dreamed of: the fairy tale prince *[who **had**]* come to make me a princess …”